# Reformatting Woes

Tags: macos, high-sierra, recovery, mac-pro

I'm running a Mac Pro 5.1 with a GTX 970 and a GT 120 installed. I've just wiped the SSD and now I'm stuck wrangling with MacOS's hyper-specific install requirements.

High Sierra won't let me install on the APFS partition it set up for itself previously so I'm trying to get to a point where I can reformat the drive entirely, but of course the recovery partition is mounted preventing me doing so.

The High Sierra USB install seems to have a common bug where it won't recognise the bluetooth mouse or keyboard. I have a wired mouse that its missing also. So that's a non-starter.

It seems my only option is Internet Recovery. However, holding alt+cmd+R just results in a black screen. EDIT: Looks like my model of mac doesn't support it at all, thanks David

Does anyone know the best course of action?

Comment: If your MacPro5,1 is a 2010 model, then I do not think you can use Internet Recovery. See [Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313).

Comment: Ah well that's something to cross off!

Comment: Have you tried installing to an external drive using a different Mac? If you can, then you could run from the external drive and reinstall macOS on the internal drive.

Comment: I did try, it spits out an error stating that it can't install as there is no firmware partition on the drive.

Comment: If you can get to 'onboard' recovery, from the existing partition on the SSD, can't you simply reformat the APFS container back to an HFS+ volume? iirc, HS wants to see HFS, then do its own conversion as part of the install.

Comment: You don't have a macOS dvd around? Try booting linux and trashing the drive.  Should not macOS detect an unformated drive and reformat?  Why doesn't it ask you to reformat. Do you have another machine around? Boot machine up in target disk mode. http://lowendmac.com/misc/06/0710.html   Target Disk Mode is started with the 'T' key held down

Comment: Buy an exterenal drive enclosure or adopter.  Place drive in enclosure. Power off.  Hold down option key ( Power on.)  until you see startup manager.  pick external drive

Comment: @historystamp - You don't even need an external enclosure. Mac Pros have 4 drive slots, though your idea does have merit. If you can't format the drive you're working from for whatever eldritch reason, format another & install to that. You can always clone it back once finished. One additional idea... take the 970 out until you have it up & running. It's not natively supported so deal with that as a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I resorted to creating a time machine backup of a working machine and using that to restore in recovery mode.

If you get stuck at the installer image telling you to turn on your bluetooth mouse, ensure that both a wired keyboard and mouse are plugged into the front.

I couldn't get it to clean install with any of the suggested workarounds. External drives and DVD images aren't supported for the High Sierra installer, nor can you reformat to HFS+. It's a stubborn pig of an OS. I'm now wrestling with getting the nvidia web drivers to work again.
Thanks for all your responses.